# Fee Reminder Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am designing a small website where user register and pay there monthly fee, I want to send them a AUTO-reminder email 5 days before there membership expire.

How should I design the database, right now I have 2 table

1. MemberDetails
2. PaymentDetails

in PaymentDetails Table I am keep a record of all the payment he/she have made, in this table when someone pay membership fee, I am also inserting a renewal date,

Please help with both how to send AUTO Email Daily using ASP.NET & is my database design is ok.

Regards

Comment: This is at least two questions, and should be split up.

Comment: This should be two entirely separate questions: database design is distinct from automating e-mail

Comment: @RedFilter - great minds 'n' all that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the email part you might take a look at...

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sending-smtp-mail-using-a-stored-procedure
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312839

To find send the emails I would install a sheduled SQL Task that runs every night and reads the database to see wether there is an email to be send or not.

That will get you started.

For the database design question... well, we could use some more information about columns, datatypes etc.